# WebApi and using Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger

I have implemented a WebApi project that has swashbuckle/swagger and a custom DelegatingHandler.
I have added a SwaggerAccessMessageHandler to check if a swagger request is made in which case I do not want my custom handler to run.

I have registered the message handler as

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new SwaggerAccessMessageHandler());
```

with the custom implementation of:

```
public class SwaggerAccessMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (IsSwagger(request))
        {
            var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    private bool IsSwagger(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/swagger");
    }
}
```

But when I can my WebApi with /swagger, I get a blank page instead of the swagger ui.

UPDATE: Ok I have removed the Swagger handler for now.
I have added a new AuthenticationHandler which checks for a valid userKey in the incoming request querystring. I cannot access swagger now.
Is there a way around this so when I want to access swagger my custom handler is not called?

Comment: Please see update above.

Answer (score 3):

You have got a blank page because you are using REST service and you are not saying anything in the body. Your browser will return a header 401 which is not visible for the user. 
You have to change response to the following

```
var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,"You are not authorized");
```

**Update** 
*`UPDATE: Ok I have removed the Swagger handler for now. I have added a new AuthenticationHandler which checks for a valid userKey in the incoming request querystring. I cannot access swagger now. Is there a way around this so when I want to access swagger my custom handler is not called?`*
No DelegatingHanlers are executed as an entry point. 
Following how webapi Pipeline works:
[image]

As you may note that you have no control over the pipeline to bypass any message handler. 
In your AuthenticationHandler, you have to check if your `PathAndQuery` contains swagger just execute the following

```
base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the SendAsync request be awaited?